# 'I want separation' vs. 'I want a separation'

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Which is correct, 'I want a separation' or 'I want separation'?

And, do they differ in meaning?

Comment: Both fragments are (or can be) grammatical, so which is correct depends entirely on what you want to say. Please give more context.

Answer (score 1):

*"I want a separation."* is correct as a sentence on its own but not *"I want separation."*

You can say this however:

*"I want separation between church and state."*

however, not this:

*"I want separation from my wife."* instead you'd say: *"I want a separation from my wife."*

Comment: is "separation" in I want separation between church and state a noun?

Comment: @user2924 No it's still a noun. The verb is "to separate". Adding "ion" to the end turns the verb into a noun.

Comment: I'm a native speaker and I think "I want separation" is perfectly acceptable as a complete sentence to indicate that the speaker wishes to be away from someone else. (Assuming their relationship with, or proximity to, someone else was already being discussed.)

Comment: @David Schwartz I guess its a dialect thing so as I would never use such an expression as a stand alone sentence.

Comment: @I guess its a dialect thing so.